# How to stop timeouts from happening in NBA 2K19

Tags: ps4, nba2k19

When I'm playing my career in NBA 2K19, I'll be in a game and at the worst points either my team or the other team will call for a timeout. Is there a way to stop this from happening? Having timeouts are a waste of time and the don't assist me in any way. These timeouts start off as being unskipable for the first 10 - 15 seconds, it really ruins the flow of the game. The game will have like 15 seconds left and the other team will call for a timeout, something else will happen in the 15 seconds left and another timeout will be called. Does anyone know what I can do about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, It isn't possible to disable time-outs in MyCareer. However, you can do this in both MyTeam and MyGm/MyLeague in the Coach Setting's menu (Coach Settings -> Timeouts).

Comment: That's a shame :( thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @DomEvans I agree. I wish i could disable the Half-Time report and the post-game interviews as well. All of those cut scenes and timeouts make the games too long.

Comment: It happens at the worst points of a game as well haha lol